# Cannot change chart.js size

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/graph2.css">
  <title>Graph</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="updating-chart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

That is the html I am using and I am using `Chart.js 2.1.4`, but I am unable to reduce the size no matter what I do.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById('updating-chart'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    startingData = {
      labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
      datasets: [
          {
             label: "Product A",
             fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
             strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
              pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              data: [65, 59, 80, 81]
          }
      ]
    };

var myLiveChart = new Chart(ctx,{
  type: 'bar',
  data: startingData,
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true
});
</script>
```

How can I fix this? I always a get a really big graph, covering the whole screen completely no matter what I change in the `canvas` HTML fields.

Help?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the contents of _/css/graph2.css_, at least anything involving the canvas or related to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the canvas in container and use CSS to set the width on that, it will size the graph.

https://jsfiddle.net/ug5eczp2/1/

HTML:

```
<section>
    <canvas id="updating-chart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle sample is what put me over the top - in chart options both `responsive: true` and `maintainAspectRatio: true` were needed

Answer (score 0):

The canvas will fit the section container. Code below.
just change the width of the section to the value you want.

```
<section>
    <canvas id="updating-chart" ></canvas>
</section>

section {
 width: 100%;
}
section > canvas {
 top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try remove the width value, specified height value only

```
<canvas id="updating-chart" height="200"></canvas>
```